# Effect of conversion of Datatimeoffset to string - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, type-conversion

Recently i came across a task where-in i need to convert DateTimeOffset(3) to string as shown below:

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), [Contact Date], 120)
```

Before conversion sample values are:

```
2015-10-23 15:43:00.000 -07:00
2015-11-04 13:27:00.000 -08:00
```

After conversion sample values are:

```
2015-10-23 15:43:00.000
2015-11-04 13:27:00.000
```

1. So is there any disadvantage or loss to my business because of this timezone removal ?
2. Is my way of conversion is correct ?
3. Any points/topics to think or pay-attention to while writing this code ?

I am using SQL Server 2012, 64 Bit, SP-1.